# sched_wakeup_granularity_ns , sched_min_granularity_ns and SCHED_RR

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

The following value from my box :

```
sysctl -A | grep "sched" | grep -v "domain"

kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled = 0
kernel.sched_cfs_bandwidth_slice_us = 5000
kernel.sched_child_runs_first = 0
kernel.sched_latency_ns = 18000000
kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 5000000
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 10000000
kernel.sched_nr_migrate = 32
kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms = 100
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
kernel.sched_shares_window_ns = 10000000
kernel.sched_time_avg_ms = 1000
kernel.sched_tunable_scaling = 1
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 3000000
```

It means in one second , 0.95 second is for SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR ,
only 0.05  reserved for SCHED_OTHER  ,  What  I  am curious is
sched_wakeup_granularity_ns   ,   I have googled it and get the explanation :

```
Ability of tasks being woken to preempt the current task. 
The smaller the value, the easier it is for the task to force the preemption
```

I think sched_wakeup_granularity_ns  only effect SCHED_OTHER task , 
the SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR should not in sleep mode , so no need to "wakeup",
am I correct ?!

and   for  sched_min_granularity_ns, the explanation is :

```
Minimum preemption granularity for processor-bound tasks. 
Tasks are guaranteed to run for this minimum time before they are preempted
```

I like to know , although SCHED_RR tasks can has 95% of cpu time , But
since the sched_min_granularity_ns value = 10000000 , it is 0.01  second ,
that means that every SCHED_OTHER get 0.01 second timeslice to run before been preempted unless it is blocked by blocking socket or sleep or else , it imply that if I have 3 tasks in core 1 for example , 2 tasks with SCHED_RR , the third task with SCHED_OTHER , and the third task just run a endless loop without blocking socket recv  and without yield , so once the third task get the cpu and run , it will run 0.01 second
and then context switch out , even the next task is priority with SCHED_RR ,
it is the right understaning for sched_min_granularity_ns usage ?!

Edit :

http://lists.pdxlinux.org/pipermail/plug/2006-February/045495.html

describe :

```
No SCHED_OTHER process may be preempted by another SCHED_OTHER process.
However a SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO process will preempt SCHED_OTHER
process before their time slice is done. So a SCHED_RR process
should wake up from a sleep with fairly good accuracy.
```

means SCHED_RR task can preempt the endless while loop without blocking even
time slice is not done ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks with a higher scheduling class "priority" will preempt all tasks with a lower priority scheduling class, regardless of any timeouts. Take a look at the below snippet from kernel/sched/core.c:

```
void check_preempt_curr(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int flags)
{
    const struct sched_class *class;

    if (p->sched_class == rq->curr->sched_class) {
        rq->curr->sched_class->check_preempt_curr(rq, p, flags);
    } else {
        for_each_class(class) {
            if (class == rq->curr->sched_class)
                break;
            if (class == p->sched_class) {
                resched_curr(rq);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * A queue event has occurred, and we're going to schedule.  In
     * this case, we can save a useless back to back clock update.
     */
    if (task_on_rq_queued(rq->curr) && test_tsk_need_resched(rq->curr))
        rq_clock_skip_update(rq, true);
}
```

for_each_class will return the classes in this order: stop, deadline, rt, fair, idle. The loop will stop when trying to preempt a task with the same scheduling class as the preempting task.

So for your question, the answer is yes, an "rt" task will preempt a "fair" task.